# Problem in populating checked checkboxes value to dynamically created dropdown list

Tags: jquery, html

I have 2 checkboxes and when I check on them I want checked data into dropdown select box. I have written the code like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="conditions[]" value="1">Sample 1
<input type="checkbox" name="conditions[]" value="2">Sample 2

<select name="Control[]"></select>
<script>
    jQuery(function ($) {
        var $conds = $('input[name="conditions[]"]'),
            $ctrl = $('select[name="Control[]"]');

        $conds.change(function () {
            if (this.checked) {
                $('<option />', {
                    value: this.value,
                    text: this.nextSibling.nodeValue
                }).appendTo($ctrl)

            } else {
                $ctrl.find('option[value="' + this.value + '"]').remove();

            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

This is working fine for me but data is not populating on appended dropdown select box.

```
var addButton = $('.add_button');
var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); 
var fieldHTML = '<p></p><div class="new_wrapper"> <select name="Control[]"></select><p></p><center><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm text-center remove_button" >Remove Package</a></center></div>';
var x = 1;
$(addButton).click(function() {
    if(x < maxField) { 
        x++; 
        $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are dynamically adding new Select boxes. These newly added select boxes were not selected as part of `$ctrl = $('select[name="Control[]"]')` when the document loads. So you need to update the selection whenever new select boxes are inserted. You can do this by inserting the line `$ctrl = $('select[name="Control[]"]')` within the `addbutton` click handler (after the new Select box is appended within `wrapper`). Hope this helps.

```
$(addButton).click(function() {
    if(x < maxField) { 
        x++; 
        $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); 
    }
    // INSERT THIS LINE. THIS WILL SELECT THE NEWLY INSERTED ELEMENTS TOO
    $ctrl = $('select[name="Control[]"]');
});
```

Comment: @NicoHaase Added explanation. Hope this helps